# Get the BytecodeArray of a Local<Function> on Nodejs c++ land

Tags: node.js, v8, embedded-v8

I'm struggling a bit with the code base of nodejs + v8.

The Goal is to get the bytecode of a function / module (looking at the code they are the same) and disassemble it using the `BytecodeArray::Disassemble` function, possibly, without side effects, a.k.a, executing the code.

The problem is that it's not clear how to get the bytecode in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(V8 developer here.) V8's API does not provide access to functions' bytecode. That's intentional, because bytecode is an internal implementation detail. For inspecting bytecode, the `--print-bytecode` flag is the way to go.

If you insist on mucking with internal details, then of course you can circumvent the public API and poke at V8's internals. From a `v8::internal::JSFunction` you can get to the `v8::internal::SharedFunctionInfo`, check whether it `HasBytecodeArray()`, and if so, call `GetBytecodeArray()` on it. Disassembling bytecode never has side effects, and never executes the bytecode. It's entirely possible that a function doesn't have bytecode at a given moment in time -- bytecode is created lazily when it's needed, and thrown away if it hasn't been used in a while. If you dig far enough, you can interfere with those mechanisms too, but...:

Needless to say, accessing internal details is **totally unsupported, not recommended**, and even if you get it to work in Node version x.y, it may break in x.(y+1), because that's what "internal details" means.

Comment: Thank you very much